# SQL query all products including those without descriptions

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have the following query to get a product ID, product name, price, description and ingredients from multiple tables.

```
SELECT TP.intProductID AS ProductID, TP.strName AS Name, TPP.decPrice AS Price,
TD.strDescription AS Description, GROUP_CONCAT( TRH.strName     SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Ingredients 
FROM TProducts TP JOIN

     TProductsPrices TPP 
     on TP.intProductID=TPP.intProductID JOIN

     TProductsDescriptions TPD 
     on TP.intProductID=TPD.intProductID JOIN

     TDescriptions TD
     on TPD.intDescriptionID=TD.intDescriptionID JOIN

     TProductsIngredients TPI
     on TPD.intProductID=TPI.intProductID JOIN

     TRawHerbs TRH
     on TPI.intIngredientID=TRH.intRawHerbID

GROUP BY TPD.intProductID;
```

The query finds all the product info the way it should, but I want to be able to include products in my results that do not have a description in the description table (and maybe return null or an empty string instead).  How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the applicable inner joins to left outer joins.  Something like this:

```
SELECT TP.intProductID AS ProductID, TP.strName AS Name, TPP.decPrice AS Price,
TD.strDescription AS Description, 
GROUP_CONCAT( TRH.strName     SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Ingredients 
FROM TProducts TP JOIN

 TProductsPrices TPP 
 on TP.intProductID=TPP.intProductID 

left JOIN TProductsDescriptions TPD 
 on TP.intProductID=TPD.intProductID 

left JOIN TDescriptions TD
 on TPD.intDescriptionID=TD.intDescriptionID 

JOIN TProductsIngredients TPI
 on TPD.intProductID=TPI.intProductID 

JOIN TRawHerbs TRH
 on TPI.intIngredientID=TRH.intRawHerbID

GROUP BY TPD.intProductID;
```

Comment: Ok I'm new to joins, I tried adding the LEFT keyword at the specified spots and the query still excludes products with no descriptions

Answer (score 0):

You have structured your query in a typical way, where you have a product table and then bring things in from it.  To keep everything in the product table, all the joins should be `left outer join`s.  Also, the joins on `productId` should go back to the original table:

```
SELECT TP.intProductID AS ProductID, TP.strName AS Name, TPP.decPrice AS Price,
       TD.strDescription AS Description,
       GROUP_CONCAT( TRH.strName     SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Ingredients 
FROM TProducts TP left outer JOIN
     TProductsPrices TPP 
     on TP.intProductID=TPP.intProductID left outer JOIN
     TProductsDescriptions TPD 
     on TP.intProductID=TPD.intProductID left outer JOIN
     TDescriptions TD
     on TPD.intDescriptionID=TD.intDescriptionID left outer JOIN
     TProductsIngredients TPI
     on TP.intProductID=TPI.intProductID left outer JOIN
     TRawHerbs TRH
     on TPI.intIngredientID=TRH.intRawHerbID
GROUP BY TPD.intProductID;
```

This will keep all the products in `TProducts`, whether or not they have matches in other tables.

In general (and especially if you are learning joins), I would recommend that you stick to one type of `join` in the `from` clause.  This structure, where everything is a `left outer join` says "keep everything in the first table".